# Run python script inside powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I want to run a python script from inside a powershell script. All of my searches lead me to questions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321970/run-python-source-file-from-powershell). I tried using Invoke-Expression, but a command window briefly opens and closes, without the expected output from the python script.

I also tried using the '&' operator, based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864765/call-ruby-script-from-powershell) question. This time, the script starts, but throws a SyntaxError. There is no such error when I run the python script separately.

EDIT:
This is the command I run:

```
& $python $MyPythonScript
```

and the variables are set like this:

```
python="C:\Python33\python.exe"
MyPythonScript="D:\MyPythonScript.py"
```

This is the output:

```
File "D:\MyPythonScript.py", line 140
print "type=%s; mean = %s; finalVariance = %s; stdDev = %s; max(x) = %s; min(x) = %s; max(y) = %s; min(y) = %s; timeDiff = %s;" %(type, mean(distance), finalVariance, stdDev,    max(x), min(x), max(y), min(y), timeDiff)
                                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The `&` operator should do what you want. Please show the exact command line you're trying to run as well as the error it throws.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the script I run and the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a Python syntax error, not a PowerShell syntax error. Put the string interpolation in parentheses:

```
print ("type=%s; ... = %s;" % (type, ..., timeDiff))
```